# Conditions and merge on Datatables while data replacement from one to another

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have two Datatables in my C# Windows Forms application;

```
DataTable dtProduct;
DataTable dtDetails;
```

`dtProduct` is being populated from `MS Access` and `dtDetails` is from `MySql`, those have following like records

**dtProduct**

```
code   | pNameOrignal
----------------------
101    | product one
220    | product two 
65     | product three
104    | product four
221    | product five 
654    | product six
```

**dtDetails**

```
id | tid | code | pNameLocal        | qty | price
-------------------------------------------------
1  |101  | 101  | some_local_name   | 2   |20.36
2  |102  | 202  | some_local_name   | 1   |15.30 // same entry as same tid and all same 
3  |102  | 202  | some_local_name   | 1   |15.30 //same entry as same tid and all same
4  |102  | 202  | some_local_name   | 1   |10.00 //same entry as same tid but price is different
5  |102  | 202  | some_local_name   | 2   |15.30 //same entry as same tid but different qty
6  |102  | 202  | some_local_name2  | 1   |15.30 //same entry as same tid but pNameLocal different
7  |103  | 202  | some_local_name   | 1   |15.30 // different entry of same product see different tid
8  |104  | 65   | some_local_name   | 5   |05.00
9  |105  | 700  | some_local_name   | 2   |07.01 // does not exist in "dtProduct"
```

I am currently looping through all records of `dtdetails` with `dtProduct` to replace original name of product `pNameOrignal` from `dtProduct` on basis of uniqueness of `code` column in both tables. my existing code look like this;

```
dtDetails.Rows
    .Cast<DataRow>()
    .Join
    (
        dtProduct.Rows.Cast<DataRow>(),
        r1 => new { p1 = r1["code"], p2 = r1["code"] },
        r2 => new { p1 = r2["code"], p2 = r2["code"] },
        (r1, r2) => new { r1, r2 }
    )
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(o => o.r1.SetField("pNameLocal", o.r2["pNameOrignal"]));
```

**What is now required**

1. need to merge or make one row for same entries with **same tid and all same** to single row by making **qty to 2 (as in current records)** by adding both and **price to 30.60 (as in current records)**

   **Explanation:** multiple records which are exactly same (duplicates) merged as one row by retaining their qty and price as per number of records.
2. entry against **tid = 105** which has `code = 700` does not exist in `dtProduct`, it will not replace `pOrignalName` from there, will keep same name as currently my code do, I need to add or concatenate "NotFound" with that name.

Comment: @JohnWu I tried to find duplicate rows but unable to merge them as one. and was just thinking to make some condition in foreach for point 2.

Comment: I don't know why votes for Close?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For second point replacing the name with matched records and adding "NotFound" for non matched records.

```
 var k =  (from d in dtDetails.AsEnumerable() join
         k1 in dtProduct.AsEnumerable() on d["code"] equals k1["code"] into dk1
         from subset in dk1.DefaultIfEmpty()
         select new { d, subset }).ToList();

foreach (var m in k)
{
    if (m.subset != null)
    {
        if (string.Equals(m.d["code"], m.subset["code"]))
        {
            m.d.SetField("pNameLocal", m.subset["pNameOrignal"]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        m.d.SetField("pNameLocal", m.d["pNameLocal"] +"NotFound");
    }
}
```

for first one try this

```
   dtDetails = dtDetails.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r => new { Col1 = r["tid"], Col2 = r["code"], Col3 = r["pNameLocal"] })
    .Select(g =>
    {
        var row1 = dtDetails.NewRow();

        row1["tid"] = g.Key.Col1;
        row1["code"] = g.Key.Col2;
        row1["pNameLocal"] = g.Key.Col3;
        row1["qty"] = g.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("qty"));
        row1["price"] = g.Sum(r => r.Field<decimal>("price"));

        return row1;
    })
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Your foeach can be reduced to:
foreach (var m in k)
            {
                var pNameOrginal = m.subset != null && string.Equals(m.d["code"], m.subset["code"]) ? m.subset["pNameOrignal"] : "NotFound";
                m.d.SetField("pNameLocal", pNameOrginal);
            }

Comment: @trighati  - Please check the updated answer for both points and let me know if it works,

Answer (score 0):

For your mentioned point 2, this can be done:

```
foreach (DataRow item in dtDetails.Rows)
{
  var pNameOriginal = dtProduct.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(i => i.Field<int>("code") == item.Field<int>("code"));
  var globalName = "NotFound";
  if (pNameOriginal != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(pNameOriginal.ItemArray[1])))
  {
    globalName = Convert.ToString(pNameOriginal.ItemArray[1]);
  }

  item["pNameLocal"] += globalName;
}
```

I am still not clear what do you want in point 1. How can the count be 2 for a group by in your case. Can you explain by taking tid 102 ?

Comment: for point 1, there two entries with same records, I need to make them one and totaling their qty and price only. I real these both transactions done separately, this is flaw in existing program which store this record. Now my requirement is to make it single row but qty and price should be consolidated.

Comment: `item["pNameLocal"] = globalName;` this will set to just NotFound, I want to concatenate NotFound with its local name

Comment: as per your explaination, this means that for 102  | 202, the quantity will be 6(sum of all quantities for 102) and the price will be the sum of all prices for 102 ?

Comment: No. only sum of 102 | 102 where pNameLocal, qty and price exactly same.  in other 4 entries price, qty and name is different from first two entries. I just want to merge as single and add their qty and price in that single row in first two rows

Comment: please correct in above comment: No. only sum of 102 | **202** where......